# codeigniter config form_validation with subfolders not working

Tags: codeigniter, validation, config, subdirectory

I have using a lot config form_validation file. It's working good!

But now I'm trying to get it work with controller in subfolder

```
/controllers/panel/users.php
```

My form_validation config file looks like

```
$config = array(    
'panel/users/edit/' => array(
        array('field' => 'login', 'label' => 'Логин', 'rules' => "trim|required|valid_email")
)
```

And my Users controller is

```
public function edit($user_id = FALSE)
{
    if ($this->input->post('save'))
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {
           // Do some
        }
    }
}
```

But $this->form_validation->run() is always return FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't designed to work this way, there was a relevant change to [ruri_string() #122](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/122) which would have fixed this but it had [other repercussions](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1306#issuecomment-5455611) and needs to be rethought.

You can call your validation rule group explicitly (drop the trailing slash from your rule group name)

```
if ($this->form_validation->run('panel/users/edit'))
```

or, if appropriate in your situation, workaround this by prepending `uri->segment(1)` to the auto-detected rule group.

`application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function run($group = '')
    {
        // Prepend URI to match subfolder controller validation rules
        $uri = ($group == '') ? $this->CI->uri->segment(1) . $this->CI->uri->ruri_string() : $group;
        return parent::run($uri);
    }

}
```